# How can we convert a dynamic value stored in uint to wei in the contract?

Tags: solidity

I have to perform something like this:

```
uint r = a wei;
```

Which displays an error, however:

```
uint r = 1 wei;
```

Doesn't throw an error.

How can I dynamically change the value of `uint` to `wei` in the contract itself?

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
uint a;
uint oneWei = 1 wei; // Or finney or...
uint r = a * oneWei;
```

Comment: No need for the variable. `a * 1 wei` should work